# Update Primefaces component in 3.1 *without enclosing inside h:form*

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have seen the question asked about how to rectify the component update code while migrating to Primefaces 3.1, preventing the exception

> Cannot find component with identifier "...." in view.

But how to update a component that is not enclosed by a form element ? Such as I need to update, using remote command, the following ouputPanel:-

> ```
> <p:outputPanel id='messageBox''>
>      ...
> </p:outputPanel>
> ```

Using :
Primefaces 3.1 with
JSF 2.1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reference it by its absolute client ID instead. The `update` attribute is by default relative to the current `UINamingContainer` component (the `<h:form>` is such one). Assuming that the given `<p:outputPanel>` is by itself not inside any other `UINamingContainer` component, then just use `update=":messageBox"`.

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":messageBox" />
```

If you're not sure, then you need to open the page in browser, do *View Source* and locate the generated HTML element of `<p:outputPanel id="messageBox">` in there, take the exact value of its `id` attribute and then prefix it with the default naming container separator `:`.

Comment: I don't too much prefer directly using JSF generated id, seeing from source, as that changes on making minor changes in the page code. Should I instead use the `binding` approach as described in your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970268/using-one-component-datatable-id-inside-composite-component

Comment: Just give all `UINamingContainer` components a fixed ID. E.g. `<h:form id="foo">`. This way JSF won't autogenerate one for them.

Comment: Thanks.. but I am still curious as to why the binding approach isn't preferred rather than giving ids to all components? :)

Comment: Because it's unnecessarily more complicated. Try to do at its simplest first. Otherwise any future developer / code reviewer might wonder "why the heck" you're using `binding` instead of `id` there.

Answer (score 0):

Specify an unique id for the `"<h:form>"` component, then use like below code to update a component

```
udpate="@(#messageBox)"
```

Comment: Please explain why the OP should give the form an unique ID and please also explain why the OP should use PFS instead of a normal client ID for this.